# \xFF not in the range of representable values for escape sequence?

Tags: c

Based on this:

> The value of an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence shall be in the
>   range of representable values for the type unsigned char for an
>   integer character constant, or the unsigned type corresponding to
>   wchar_t for a wide character constant.

the octal sequence range is [0,255] for byte=8bits.

but further they used an example of:

> EXAMPLE 3 Even if eight bits are used for objects that have type char, the construction '**\x123'** specifies an integer character constant containing only one character,

Isn't that a violation of the first constraint as `\x123` which exceeds 255 ?

Comment: Sorry I took the wrong example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes  `'\x123'` is a violation of the when `char` is 8-bits as `'\x123'` which exceeds 255.

The is an example of what one should *not* use.  The C spec example goes on to say:

> ... To specify an integer character constant containing the two characters whose values are `'\x12'` and `'3'`, the construction `'\0223'` may be used, since an octal escape sequence is terminated after three octal digits.  (The value of this two-character integer character constant is implementation-deﬁned.) C11 §6.4.4.4  14

`'\xFF'` is in range, but `'\xFF$'`, where `$` is some hexadecimal character, is not in range.

---

In other words, a hexadecimal escape sequence does not stop until it exhaust all hexadecimal characters.  It is not limited, to say 2 characters, on a 8-bit `char` system.

Answer (score 0):

ideone issues a warning and treats the literal as though it was \x23

```
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char x = '\x123';
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}

prog.c:5:11: warning: hex escape sequence out of range
  char x = '\x123';
           ^~~~~~~

Success time: 0 memory: 9432 signal:0
35
```

so whatever you are quoting is not very good

Comment: "whatever you are quoting is not very good" appears to be the C spec.